# Simply drawing electronical circuits, no simulation, no PCB

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, electronics

I am looking for a circuit design software for beginners, ideally even kids.

Requirements:

- runs on Windows 10 (1903 and later is ok)
- works offline. For my uses, people do not have Internet connection at all. I can download it once (on a different PC) and install it on the PCs via USB Stick, but once that is done, there's no Internet any more
- is gratis (or at least less than 5 € one time cost)
- can design electronical circuits (low voltage)
- comes with the "usual" symbols for resistors, capacitors etc. I don't want to draw them by myself, e.g. with Inkscape, as suggested by other answers here on SR.SE. I have done it with Inkscape and I don't want to do it any more.
- has the IEC version of the symbols
- can save files and open again (can be proprietary)

Optional, but highly demanded:

- export as graphics (either bitmap or vector). The export should be high quality printable, not just a 1 px black line which gets lots when printing.

Optional:

- export as vector graphics (SVG)

Non-requirements:

- can design electrical circuits (high voltage / mains)
- real world component selection
- PCB layout
- Circuit simulation
- US version of electronical symbols
- save or export into standard electronics exchange formats

Note that the software may have the non-requirements, but having them should not make the UI complex.

I see that [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) uses an online editor from [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com). Regarding usability and features, this looks close to what I want, but it is online only.

I have tried:

- [Fritzing](https://fritzing.org), but it does not have IEC symbols. It's possible to patch these, but that needs to be repeated after each update, which is not suitable for children.

Comment: www.diagrams.net/blog/diagrams-offline might have what you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer. High quality answers explain how the requirements are fulfilled and don't just provide a link.

Comment: After a while I found the electronical symbols. Sorry I don't like it for several reasons: a) each symbol can be scaled individually, which makes the circuit look ugly. b) the SPST switch does not align with the grid. c) it's not possible to select US or IEC, but we have all symbols available (even UK) all time, which is error-prone. d) it's possible to mix electronics with BPMD or UML e) Labels for the electronical symbols have to be placed manually and they don't move with the component.

Comment: This is not my field, but these articles might be relevant. https://www.engineersgarage.com/online-offline-circuit-design-software-for-beginners-and-professionals/  https://www.electronicsforu.com/special/cool-stuff-misc/open-source-circuit-design-software

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/)
It has components from the most basics to programmable Arduino.
Even has some sample ready to use circuits, doesn't require any installation(works in browser), saves your circuits as you demanded, can export the circuit, has the standard symbols and yes it does have simulation(up to you if you want to use it or not).
Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, where do I download it?

Comment: Sir you don't need to download or install, as I mentioned It works in your web browser as it is an online platform.

Comment: for your reference, here are some circuits (using Arduino though, but they are just for reference you can make without it also according to need):  [Basic blink](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/jZ1n8mRZgjo-basic-blink/editel?sharecode=4mcJ4Y9f5kXe6rdahf4M7wmjBIY603SEqYsdrAfuMG4)   [arduino servo](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/iHUuLRgahKR-servo/editel?sharecode=hWk5_0xHr1Pi0DFNUaxvoX3DX6-Seow3q24djgoTjyY)

Comment: Ok, but I was explicity asking for an offline tool

Comment: Sorry, I must've missed that one. though it works on minimal data requirements(in terms of consumption and speed). Then too, if you may please state the exact problem with the tool being online so that I can decide that if I should share the other tools/software that I use (as they too might require an internet connection at some point).

Comment: For my uses, people do not have Internet connection at all. I can download it once and install it on the PCs, but once that is done, there's no Internet any more

Answer (score 0):

I used Eagle to draw schematic during my undergraduate years. It is one of the common tool used by student and hobbyist.

Download it here: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/free-download

Comment: I suspect this is much more involved than what the OP is requesting.